# ¿Como busco un elemento de un arreglo con objeto en java desde otro metodo diferente?

Tags: java, array, arraylist, objeto

[image: Método donde busco extraer elementos y mostrar el resto del arreglo en base un dato]
[image: Método donde ingreso la información]
Método donde busco extraer elementos y mostrar el resto del arreglo en base  un dato

Comment: Hola por favor añade tu código como texto para que la comunidad pueda ayudarte.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score -1):

Buen dia, le tenes que pasar como parametro al `buscar()` el arreglo.

```
buscar(Alumno[] arregloAlumnos){}
```